# Multiple loops work except the outermost loop

Tags: javascript, loops, google-apps-script, google-sheets, increment

I have a script that does the following.

From **innermost** to outermost:

1. Iterates over each object property. (For in) !

   ```
   for (var j in jsobj) {  
                 var headerRow = Object.keys(jsobj).sort();
                 var row = headerRow.map(function(key){ return jsobj[key]});
                 var contents = [row];
                 var headers = [headerRow];
                 sheets[counter].getRange(1+i, 1, contents.length, headerRow.length ).setValues(contents);
        }
   ```
2. Iterates over each column containing an object

   ```
     for (var i=0; i < col-5; i++) {  
   var json = sheet.getRange(arr[m-1],i+6).getValue(); //First value should be row position from VLOOKUP.
   var jsobj = JSON.parse(json);
   ```

Now from this point, I want to run another loop, var m is a changing value and thus should give different results.

```
for (var m=item; m > 0; m--) {

counter++
```

I have an enclosed loop that will generate an array of values for "m".

```
var arr = []; 
      for (var y = 0; y < folios.length; y++) {
        if(folios[y] == name){
          arr.push(y);

        }
      }
```

First two innermost loops work as intended however I can't seem to be able to get it working for the outer loop. I'll provide a copy of the spreadsheet and the full code below:

```
function createTable() {

  var doc = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1Jv3E51r5zMuMLmn0qkCRjQBBRJHK_QTSdOeCSLRG7Do");

  var sheet = doc.getSheetByName("json");
  var sheet2 = doc.getSheetByName("tabla de frecuencias");
  var sheet7 = doc.getSheetByName("tf2");




  //Variable framework
  var prelast = sheet.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
  var last = prelast.filter(String).length;
  var folio = sheet.getRange(last,3).getValue();
  var folios = sheet.getRange("D1:D").getValues();
  var range = sheet.getRange("C1:C");
  var name = sheet.getRange(last,4).getValue();
  var sheets = [sheet2,sheet7];
  var counter = -1
  var col =  sheet.getLastColumn();


      var arr = []; 
      for (var y = 0; y < folios.length; y++) { //This creates an array for later use.
        if(folios[y] == name){
          arr.push(y);

        }
      }

         var item = arr.length;

    for (var m=item; m > 0; m--) { //This is the loop that is not working.

    counter++ //When the first iteration completes, this should increase for later use.


      for (var i=0; i < col-5; i++) { //This and the below loop work as intended.



        var json = sheet.getRange(arr[m-1],i+6).getValue(); //This is a critical point where M decreases its value all the way to 0 to fetch an entire row from my JSON sheet. It works in testing only for one row. I want it to go through each row in the array and write the values on different sheets, or even in the same sheet. 

        var jsobj = JSON.parse(json);


        for (var j in jsobj) { //Works!

          var headerRow = Object.keys(jsobj).sort();
          var row = headerRow.map(function(key){ return jsobj[key]});
          var contents = [row];
          var headers = [headerRow];



          sheets[counter].getRange(1+i, 1, contents.length, headerRow.length ).setValues(contents); //Let me explain: var sheets contain an array of two sheets, I want the script to write over each sheet based on the outermost loop.

        }


      }


    }
```

Finally my spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Jv3E51r5zMuMLmn0qkCRjQBBRJHK_QTSdOeCSLRG7Do/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks for stopping by.

Comment: This is a lot of code and your spreadsheet has even more code, can you try to create a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: I have sanitized the spreadsheet and script inside it to only contain the relevant part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue at the that it fails within the first iteration of the loop.
`col` is the last column index in the spreadsheet, in all rows in the json sheet this is empty and trying to parse the empty string as a JSON breaks the script.

After `var json = sheet.getRange(last,i+6).getValue();` or your `arr[m]` alternative you need to check if the string is empty and if so break or continue.

```
if (json === "") {break;}
```

After doing that it just fails because it then tries to write to the third sheet , because there are 3 instalaciones rows but only two sheets to write to.

Comment: Excelent it worked! I can add extra sheets for that. Thank you so much.